# The product of two group varieties is a group variety

Tags: group-theory, universal-algebra

I am struggling with exercise 3.9.6 presented in Clifford Bergman's book "Universal Algebra. Fundamentals and Selected Topics". The exercise is as following:

Let $V$ and $W$ be varieties of groups. Define $V \cdot W$ to be the class of all groups $A$ containing a normal subgroup $B$ such that $B \in V$ and $A/B \in W$. Prove that $V \cdot W$ is a variety.

I strongly suspect that this task requires from us using the algebraic isomorphisms theorems but I have no idea how to start.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It might worth adding the 'group-theory' tag

Comment: Thank you for the advice !

Comment: Do you know Birkhoff's HSP theorem?

Comment: Of course I do. The problem I am struggling with is technical details of prooving that $V \cdot W$ is closed under those three operations.

Comment: @LambdaStudent001 - then I suggest to show some effort of your own and see where we can help. This site is not meant to be throwing a problem and asking for a solution. You could start with the *subgroup* property, so let $G \in \mathcal{V}\mathcal{W}$, so there is an $N \unlhd G$, $N \in \mathcal{V}$ and $G/N \in \mathcal{W}$. Let $H \leq G$, show that $H \cap N \in \mathcal{V}$ and $H/(H \cap N) \in \mathcal{W}$. And so on.

Comment: @LambdaStudent001: it is far from obvious from your question that you know the HSP theorem. Stamping your feet and saying "of course I do" doesn't help us to answer your question. Please learn to write better questions, showing what you have tried and why.